# Help with sentence: don't come in 

Tags: punctuation, writing, sentence

Which of the following is correct:

1) Don't come in, I'm busy.
2) Don't come in; I'm busy.
3) Don't come in.  I'm busy.
4) Don't come in I'm busy.

And why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of the four choices, the only one that doesn't work is 4.

> Don't come in, I'm busy.

is a comma splice, but acceptable informally.

> Don't come in; I'm busy.

is perfectly fine, but a bit musty and over-educated for many uses.

> Don't come in. I'm busy.

is probably the simplest, but may not express the connectedness of the two sentences sufficiently for your taste. (Note: It doesn't have to. Apposition is a form of connection.)

You might also consider

> Don't come in: I'm busy.

The colon indicates that "I'm busy" is a direct explanation of the command that comes before it.

But of the four I myself would go with No. 3.

Comment: Also, perhaps: "Don't come in...I'm busy."

Comment: @Josh: read my first sentence.

Comment: sorry, I can't count!

Comment: Hey, the semicolon isn't "musty and over-educated" at all! Take that back. :p